# How to run JMeter Webdriver samplers on a remote machine

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run JMeter Webdriver samplers in IE on a remote machine. I have changed `remote_hosts` to the IP address of the remote machine. JMeter server on the remote machine is also started. When I run the tests from the JMeter GUI on the local machine `(Run->Remote Start menu)` I can see the command line window in remote machine showing

> "Started the test..."

and immediately

> "Finished the test..."

So the test runs but nothing actually happens.

I must be missing some configuration.

Can someone please help?

Comment: did you add also plugins in remote machines? check the log in remove machine and add the error in log to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to install the same [Selenium/WebDriver Support](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin to the remote slave(s). This can be done either by copying the whole JMeter installation to the slave host(s) or using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) on each slave.
2. You need to download [Internet Explorer Driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) binary and put it to the same location as on the master host.

---

In case of any problems check `jmeter-server.log` file on remote slave - normally it should contain the root cause (or clue on what is wrong)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri once again.

Comment: When I provide "remote_hosts=<some ip address>,127.0.0.1" in the properties files then it runs the tests only in one client (first ip). I was expecting it run concurrent tests on both the clients.Am I missing out on something? Thanks in advance,I know you have the answer

Comment: You need to run `jmeter-server` on the same machine where you're launching tests. Master node doesn't execute anything per se, it just configures **remote slaves** so if you want to run your Selenium test on master node as well you need to launch a **jmeter slave** on the same node. More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)